# Calculating $\lim_{x\to 1} \, \int -\frac{i \text{Li}_2\left(x-x^2\right)}{\sqrt{3} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)} \, dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

How can we force *Mathematica* to compute this limit? 
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \, \int -\frac{i \text{Li}_2\left(x-x^2\right)}{\sqrt{3} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)} \, dx$$

It seems it works when trying $x\to 0$, but not in the previous case. What possibilities might I have?

This is the command I used

```
Limit[
  Integrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), x], 
  x -> 1]
```

Comment: Does this question make sense mathematically? Since you have an indefinite integral, there's the arbitrary constant to consider. $\lim_{x\to1}\int_1^x f(t)dt = 0$, but $\lim_{x\to1}\int_0^x f(t)dt$ might not.

Comment: @ChipHurst I think you didn't see the picture behind because it's about calculating $\int_0^1$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks.

Comment: Actually I also (in line with @ChipHurst) do not see what do you mean by taking the limit of indefinite integral. It is actually an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 8):

Adding the assumption that x is real (which it is in this case) and then simplifying allows *Mathematica* to compute a symbolic answer:

```
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals];
Integrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), x];
Simplify @ %;
Limit[%, x -> 1]
```

On 10.1 these commands yield the following (after some computation time):

```
1/108 ((8 π^3+9 π Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])]^2-72 π Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])] Log[(I+Sqrt[3])/(-I+Sqrt[3])]+36 π Log[(I+Sqrt[3])/(-I+Sqrt[3])]^2-36 π PolyLog[2,(-1)^(1/3)]-36 π PolyLog[2,-(-1)^(2/3)]-36 π PolyLog[2,1-(-1)^(1/3)]-72 π PolyLog[2,1+(-1)^(2/3)]+36 π PolyLog[2,(I+Sqrt[3])/(-I+Sqrt[3])])/Sqrt[3]+(1/Sqrt[3])I (-54 Log[1+I Sqrt[3]] Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])]^2+54 Log[-I+Sqrt[3]] Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])]^2+12 π^2 Log[I+Sqrt[3]]-24 π^2 Log[(I+Sqrt[3])/(-I+Sqrt[3])]+108 Log[I+Sqrt[3]] PolyLog[2,(-1)^(1/3)]+108 Log[I+Sqrt[3]] PolyLog[2,-(-1)^(2/3)]+108 Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])] PolyLog[2,1-(-1)^(1/3)]-108 Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])] PolyLog[2,(1-I Sqrt[3])/(2 (1+(-1)^(2/3)))]+108 Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])] PolyLog[2,(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])]-108 Log[(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])] PolyLog[2,(I+Sqrt[3])/(-I+Sqrt[3])]+108 PolyLog[3,1-(-1)^(1/3)]+216 PolyLog[3,1+(-1)^(2/3)]+216 PolyLog[3,(1-I Sqrt[3])/(2 (1+(-1)^(2/3)))]-108 PolyLog[3,(I-Sqrt[3])/(I+Sqrt[3])]+108 PolyLog[3,(I+Sqrt[3])/(-I+Sqrt[3])]+324 Zeta[3]))
```

With `FullSimplify` this can be reduced to:

```
(π (26 π^2+36 I π Log[2]+(-5+4 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1,1/6]+(5-12 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1,1/3]+(5+12 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1,2/3]+(-5-4 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1,5/6])+840 I Zeta[3])/(216 Sqrt[3])
```

Both results have a numerical value of 1.04978 + 4.17538 I

This value can be independently confirmed with `NLimit` and without using any assumptions:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
Integrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), x];
NLimit[%, x -> 1]
```

> ```
> 1.04978 + 4.17538 I
> ```

Note that with `NLimit`, setting the `Direction` option to I or -I yields a different limit, the same one that bbgodfrey found:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
Integrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), x];
NLimit[%, x -> 1, Direction -> I]
```

> ```
> 3.03883 + 1.54225 I
> ```

Comment: Many thanks (+1)

Comment: And you are Ok with the fact that adding a constant to the integral is still the same indefinite integral?

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to let x = 1 + eps, expand the integral (antiderivative) into a series with respect to eps, and then let eps -> 0.

Mathematica 10.1 quickly returns the result to which some "beautifying" was done afterwards by hand.

Here's the code

```
FullSimplify[
 Limit[Series[
     Integrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[
             3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), x] /. 
      x -> 1 + \[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}, 
     Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0] // Normal // 
   Simplify, \[Epsilon] -> 0]]

(*
(\[Pi] (26 \[Pi]^2 + 
    36 I \[Pi] Log[2] + (-5 + 4 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1, 1/
      6] + (5 - 12 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1, 1/
      3] + (5 + 12 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1, 2/
      3] + (-5 - 4 I Sqrt[3]) PolyGamma[1, 5/6]) + 
 840 I Zeta[3])/(216 Sqrt[3])
*)

%//N

(* 1.04978 + 4.17538 I *)
```

This conincides with Nick's solution.

Comment: Many thanks (+1)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: material reordered for clarity**

The formal definition of the [PolyLogorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) is `Sum[z^k/k^n, {n, 1, Infinity}]`, which converges for `Abs[z] < 1`.  Thus, the integrand can be integrated term-wise.

```
summand = Integrate[-I (x (1 - x))^k/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x)), x]
     // FullSimplify
(* ((-1)^(1/6) x^(1 + k) AppellF1[1 + k, -k, 1, 2 + k, x, -(-1)^(2/3) x])/
   (Sqrt[3] (1 + k)) *)
```

The value of `summand` at `x = 1` is

```
summand /. x -> 1
(* ((-1)^(1/6) 2^(-1 - 2 k) Sqrt[\[Pi]/3] Gamma[2 + k] 
   Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + k, 2 + 2 k, -(-1)^(2/3)])/((1 + k) Gamma[3/2 + k]) *)
```

Of course, `summand /. x -> 0` is `0`.  The first ten terms of the series are adequate to give a good answer.

```
Sum[(summand /. x -> 1) k^-2, {k, 1, 10}] // N // Chop
(* 0.110503 *)
```

This same result can be obtained by numerically integrating the integrand from `x = 0` to `x = 1`.

```
NIntegrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), {x, 0, 1}] 
    // Chop
(* 0.110503 *)
```

For completeness, note that the integrand is well behaved throughout the range of integration.

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  ReIm[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x)))]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

(The Real and Imaginary parts are blue and orange, respectively.)

However, it is important to remember that the anti-derivative of any function is determined only up to an arbitrary constant.  Thus,

```
int = Integrate[-((I PolyLog[2, x - x^2])/(Sqrt[3] (-(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x))), x];
int /. x -> .9999
(* 3.03883 + 1.54225 I*)
```

gives a different answer, because `Integrate` has thrown in a different constant in this case.  Varying x shows that this numerical solution has converged.

```
(int /. x -> .99999) - (int /. x -> .9999)
(* 2.47505*10^-9 - 1.42876*10^-9 I *)
```

Which result is preferable depends on how the OP plans to use it.

Comment: Many thanks (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist  Please note the cautionary statement at the end of my Answer.  I recommend that you add to your question how you plan to use the result, which may impact how it should be derived.